# Why is using the bpf_trace_printk function causing eBPF program not to load?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, ebpf

This is the code for my very simply program.

```
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>

int counter = 0;

SEC("xdp")
int hello(void *ctx)
{
        bpf_printk("Hello World %d", counter);
        counter++;
        return XDP_PASS;
}

char LICENSE[] SEC("license") = "Dual BSD/GPL";
```

This is the output I get when I try to load the above program.

```
> bpftool prog load hello.bpf.o /sys/fs/bpf/hello
libbpf: prog 'hello': BPF program load failed: Invalid argument
libbpf: prog 'hello': -- BEGIN PROG LOAD LOG --
btf_vmlinux is malformed
reg type unsupported for arg#0 function hello#4
0: R1=ctx(off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0
; bpf_printk("Hello World %d", counter);
0: (18) r6 = 0xffff80000abe2000       ; R6_w=map_value(off=0,ks=4,vs=4,imm=0)
2: (61) r3 = *(u32 *)(r6 +0)          ; R3_w=scalar(umax=4294967295,var_off=(0x0; 0xffffffff)) R6_w=map_value(off=0,ks=4,vs=4,imm=0)
3: (18) r1 = 0xffff000006d51b10       ; R1_w=map_value(off=0,ks=4,vs=15,imm=0)
5: (b7) r2 = 15                       ; R2_w=15
6: (85) call bpf_trace_printk#6
unknown func bpf_trace_printk#6
processed 5 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 0 peak_states 0 mark_read 0
-- END PROG LOAD LOG --
libbpf: prog 'hello': failed to load: -22
libbpf: failed to load object 'hello.bpf.o'
Error: failed to load object file
```

When I remove the bpf_printk method, everything loads perfectly, but adding that in causes it not to load. I took this code from Liz Rice's book on eBPF, so I'm not sure why this doesn't work. I tried using bpf_trace_printk directly, but that also failed as well. I would appreciate some guidance on how to proceed.

Comment: What is your host environment?

Comment: Could you share what kernel version you are running and under what privileges (root?) you are running the `bpftool prog load` command?